# variable with multiple lines.delete first two lines in perl

Tags: perl, unix, solaris

I have a result of an sql query.it returns some 10 rows like below:

if i do the below in my perl script.

```
print $result
```

it gives me the output :

```
 key       value                            
 ----------- ------------------------------ 
  1428116300 0003000                        
   560779655 0003001                        
   173413463 0003002                        
      315642 0003003                        
  1164414857 0003004                        
   429589116 0003005
```

i just want to acheive that the first two lines to be deleted. and store the rest of each line in an array.
could any body please tell how do i achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With something like :

```
my @lines = split /\n/, $result;
splice @lines,0,2;
```

---

Explanations :

`split /\n/, $result` is cutting your variable into an array of lines.

`grep  /^[\s\d]+$/` is filtering this array, and only keeps the elements that are a single line of spaces or digits (thus removing the first two lines)

Comment: @Orabig.Thanks .the logic is working.but i want to delete first two lines only.i donot want to use grep here.I will change your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Data-independent, little roundabout way: If you print $result out in a file, you can

```
use Tie::File;

tie @lines, Tie::File, $file or die "can't update $file: $!";
delete $lines[1];
delete $lines[2];
```

(untested)